# How badly would lower-than-average testosterone affect strength-only gains?

Tags: testosterone, goals, hormones

For males and females.

For this example, I am male, so let's focus on males. First of all, *assumptions*:

**Muscle size is not important to me**. I don't feel as though I have to build muscle to be attractive, and I'm fine with my own size, so any benefits/assumptions aside, **muscle mass means virtually nada to me**. Including this in this mix, a certain figure of testosterone in any *assumptions* would not hinder goals since building size is not a priority to me, so all figures representing T-levels in this regard are not relevant.

It would be wise not to assume building X specific amount of muscle is a top-priority to me.

What is my priority, you ask? *Strength*. Studies correlate testosterone with muscle strength in regards to muscle size, yes, *but there's no hard evidence that both must go perfectly hand-in-hand to improve one*.

In other words, there's no 100% correlation from muscle strength potential to muscle size and mass. Pre-pubescent children have built phenomenal strength with low-testosterone. People who have undergone gonadectomies have not been doomed to succeed in building strength either, although can be very hard.

In short, assuming I have low-testosterone, how limited would I be in building purely strength?

Strength is not just muscle mass but potential: myofibril execution, nervous system, mind/body control, etc.

My current routines/maxes:

Squat: 1 time a week, 3 reps, 50-80 lbs., 100% deep.

Biceps curl: 50-80 lbs., 1-3 reps, 100% perfect form, once or twice a week.

Deadlift max: 280 lbs.

Squat max: 120 lbs.

My goal:

Deadlift max: 600 lbs.

Squat max: 300 lbs.

NOTE: I have absolutely no sexual dysfunction symptoms associated with low-T (but could still have it). Consider this question, to some degree, hypothetical, because I'm assuming I have low-T based on failure to improve much strength. I'm not seeing any physicians/doctors/etc., so don't bother telling me to.

Comment: Have you looked at other things that hamper progress, like nutrition and rest? If you're not eating enough of the right stuff or getting enough rest/sleep, it doesn't matter what your T-levels are. Also, your squat and deadlift goals should probably be closer to each other, unless you have a good reason for the discrepancy.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to hear it, but it's a reality that anyone who's messed around with steroids and hormones can attest to: the only way you verify test levels is medically. There are saliva testosterone tests you can buy online (amazon, etc) without a physician's reference but honestly you can't "eyeball" your testosterone levels: it needs to come from a test.

> I'm not seeing any physicians/doctors/etc., so don't bother telling me
>   to.

Specifically looking at research though, there is evidence that testosterone is directly linked with strength (amongst other composition changes). From a 2001 study in the [American Journal of Physiology - Endocrinology and Metabolism](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11701431):

> We conclude that changes in circulating testosterone concentrations,
>   induced by GnRH agonist and testosterone administration, are
>   associated with testosterone dose- and concentration-dependent changes
>   in fat-free mass, muscle size, **strength and power**, fat mass,
>   hemoglobin, HDL cholesterol, and IGF-I levels, in conformity with a
>   single linear dose-response relationship.

Even in [this 1996 study](http://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJM199607043350101) shows an increase of strength with an increase of testosterone, even with no exercise:

> Among the men in the no-exercise groups, those given testosterone had
>   greater increases than those given placebo in muscle size in their
>   arms (mean [±SE] change in triceps area, 424±104 vs. -81±109 mm2;
>   P<0.05) and legs (change in quadriceps area, 607±123 vs. -131±111 mm2;
>   P<0.05) **and greater increases in strength** in the bench-press (9±4 vs.
>   -1±1 kg, P<0.05) and squatting exercises (16±4 vs. 3±1 kg, P<0.05). The men assigned to testosterone and exercise had greater increases in
>   fat-free mass (6.1±0.6 kg) and muscle size (triceps area, 501±104 mm2;
>   quadriceps area, 1174±91 mm2) than those assigned to either
>   no-exercise group, and **greater increases in muscle strength**
>   (bench-press strength, 22±2 kg; squatting-exercise capacity, 38±4 kg)
>   than either no-exercise group. Neither mood nor behavior was altered
>   in any group.

Looking at this part of your question, I'm not sure what you mean:

> Pre-pubescent children have built phenomenal strength with
>   low-testosterone.

The [youth squat records hang out in the ~300lb range (for ~220lb+ people)](http://www.goheavy.net/records/viewrecordsetgroup.aspx?recordsetgroupguid=6de22027-43ee-447d-b3ab-d0eb29677fd0), while certainly strong (and that's post puberty), the compounding effect of training and a healthy endocrine system over the years are what have people moving triple that around on their backs.